# Rails/Devise - preventing spam signups?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, spam-prevention

We have been noticing a large number (~3400) of fake signups over the last year and have not been able to determine where they are coming from. Common parameters:

- They often come from weird, yet validly formatted, email address (many in the .ru TLD or from thefmail.com)
- Some use cyrillic or arabic characters in their name (we are basically focused only on US English speakers by our content)
- They do NOT trigger the Intercom.io javascript for account signup notifications
- They somehow defeat reCaptcha 3
- They sometimes use URLs for their username
- They don't confirm (devise_confirmable)

We've been handling these by disabling the accounts, and there's obviously a few items above we could use to identify these before they even get created, but I was wondering if someone's cracked this nut already or if there's some simple best practices (pwned db check?) that might cut this down to a dull roar or out entirely.

The two big "I don't get its" are bypassing the JS and defeating recaptcha. Is this just mechanical-turking?

Answer (score 1):

Do you know whether these users have been created by the same IP address? (probably not). Are the accounts sporadically created or are they created in batches? The gem [`rack-attack`](https://github.com/rack/rack-attack) could be used to mitigate this issue, especially if at least one of these conditions is satisfied. It also comes with some sort of `fail2ban` filter which could be helpful, as it is designed to detect suspicious requests from 'misbehaving' clients.
I also can't understand how they possibly bypassed recaptcha.

Comment: We do have `rack-attack` setup, but mostly focused on wordpress hack URLs and people trying to brute force `/login`. We'll add the registration path too, but I believe these are different IPs, typically from a similar IP range (123.123.123.xxx, where the last octet changes). Something along these lines? https://andycroll.com/ruby/protect-your-sign-up-form-using-rack-attack/

Comment: Yes, that could be very helpful because it prevents clients from creating many accounts per minute. I have a similar configuration in one of my Rails projects. Just take into account that it might prevent some legitimate sign-ups, especially if clients access the site from a proxy server or a VPN (depending on the popularity of the site and the way in which users access it).